# Mail sent with mutt is not dkim signed

Tags: openbsd, mutt, rspamd

On OpenBSD 6.6 I'm sending mail with `mutt` and it isn't being DKIM signed.

I am new to OpenBSD, `mutt`, and `rspamd`, so any help much appreciated.

```
$ cat ~/.muttrc

set editor = nano
set pager = lynx
set visual = lynx
auto_view text/html
alternative_order text/plain text/enriched text/html
set mbox_type = Maildir
set folder = "~/Maildir"
set mbox = "~/Maildir"
set spoolfile ="~/Maildir"
set record = "+sent"
set trash = "+trash"
set postponed = "+drafts"

set realname = "User Name"
set from = "username@example.com"

set mailcap_path = ~/.mailcap
```

--

```
$ cat /etc/rspamd/local.d/dkim_signing.conf
allow_username_mismatch = true;

domain {
    example.com {
        path = "/etc/mail/dkim/example.com.key";
        selector = "20200226";
    }
}
```

--

```
$ cat /etc/mail/smtpd.conf                                                                   
pki example.com cert "/etc/ssl/example.com.fullchain.pem"
pki example.com key "/etc/ssl/private/example.com.key"

filter check_dyndns phase connect match rdns regex { '.*\.dyn\..*', '.*\.dsl\..*' } junk 

filter check_rdns phase connect match !rdns junk

filter check_fcrdns phase connect match !fcrdns junk

filter senderscore proc-exec "filter-senderscore -junkBelow 70 -slowFactor 5000"

filter rspamd proc-exec "filter-rspamd"

table aliases file:/etc/mail/aliases

listen on all tls pki example.com \
    filter { check_dyndns, check_rdns, check_fcrdns, senderscore, rspamd }

listen on all port submission tls-require pki example.com auth filter rspamd

action "local_mail" maildir junk alias <aliases>
action "outbound" relay helo example.com

match from any for domain "example.com" action "local_mail"
match for local action "local_mail"

match from any auth for any action "outbound"
match for any action "outbound"
```

Comment: And are e-mails sent using other software DKIM signed? Are you sure mutt is configured to use your SMTP server where you configured the DKIM? Because there's no smtp configuration in your muttrc.

Comment: @JakubJindra The only other program sending mail is the default system messages from `root`, which are sent to external address and are not DKIM signed. The `mutt` package is compiled with `SENDMAIL="/usr/sbin/sendmail"`, so it should be using `smtpd`.

Comment: yes, but then it's most probably not mutt question but opensmtpd or whatever you use as a stmp.